# How do you dynamically module.export all files in a folder?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, node-modules

I'm trying to dynamically export modules. I'm close but can't figure out how to fix my syntax.

Hard coded:

```js
// index.js inside folder 'models'
const { User } = require('./User');
const { Token } = require('./Token');
const { Session } = require('./Session');

module.exports = {
    User,
    Token,
    Session,
};
```

Dynamically coded (doesn't work):

```js
// index.js inside folder 'models'
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

module.exports = () => {
    fs.readdirSync(__dirname).forEach((file) => {
        if (file === 'index.js') return false;
        const fullName = path.join(__dirname, file);
        
        if (file.toLowerCase().indexOf('.js')) {
            // I think this somehow needs to be destructured like 
            // `return {require(fullName)}` or 
            // `require(fullName)[fullName]` I think
            require(fullName);
        }
    });
};
```

Elsewhere in my code, I initialize it based on the folder name:

```js
// server.js
require('./models')();
```

Comment: a) why export a function instead of an object b) yes, your function doesn't return anything c) why limit the iteration to `….js` files? None of the three module identifiers in your hardcoded version have `.js` on them.

Comment: You might be looking for `Object.assign({}, ...fs.readdirSync(__dirname).map(name => { …; return require(…); }))`

Comment: @Bergi Thanks, you're right a) object is better b) I see c) project specific. Yes putting the modules into an object was what I was missing. Got it working now from someone's answer below. Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your dynamic export will not work because you are not returning anything to the exported function.

Try this code as your dynamic model export file

```
// index.js inside folder 'models'
const fs = require('fs')
const path = require('path')

const models = {}

fs.readdirSync(__dirname)
  .filter(file => file !== 'index.js')
  .forEach(file => {
    const fullName = path.join(__dirname, file)

    if (file.toLowerCase().endsWith('.js')) {
      // Removes '.js' from the property name in 'models' object
      const [filename] = file.split('.')
      models[filename] = require(fullName)[filename]
    }
  })

module.exports = models
```

This approach no longer exports a function so your require in `server.js` should now look like this

```
// server.js
require('./models');
```